# Why do i need to refresh page to view new value of ng-show

Tags: angularjs, firebase, registration, ng-show

Hey guys so i am using firebase and angular to build a sample application.

This is the registration function

```
$scope.register = function (){ 
    Authentication.register($scope.user)
        .then(function(user){
            Authentication.login($scope.user);                                                      
        })
        .then(function(user){
            $timeout(function(){
                $location.path('/meetings');
            }, 5);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            $scope.message = error.toString();
        });


} //register
```

this function calls to methods in this factory

```
myApp.factory('Authentication', function($firebase,
                $firebaseAuth,$location, FIREBASE_URL){

    var ref = new Firebase (FIREBASE_URL);
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);      

    var myObject = {
        login : function (user){
                return auth.$authWithPassword({
                    email: user.email,
                    password: user.password
                });
        }, // login

        logout: function (){
            return auth.$unauth();
        },
        register : function (user){
            return auth.$createUser(user.email,user.password);
        } //register
    } //myObject
    return myObject;
});
```

here is the status.js controller which changes my index based on whether the user is logged in or not

```
auth.$onAuth(function(authData){
        if (authData){
            console.log("i entered authData");
            $scope.userStatus = authData.password.email;

        } else {

            $scope.userStatus = false;
        }
    });
```

part of index.html file

```
<div class="userinfo" 
ng-controller="StatusController"  ng-show="userStatus">
  <span class="user">Hi {{userStatus}}</span>
  <a href="#" ng-click="logout()">Log Out</a>
 </div>
```

my problem is that the ng-view needs a page refresh to show the new value. its not showing it automatically but my code works. if i refresh the page manually i can see that the user got registered and logged in.

Search for about 2 hours now and $scope.$apply here does nt seem to be the case.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't know the answer, but the documentation refers to `onAuth` instead of `$onAuth`, could it be that?

Comment: Try to put the ng-show not inline with the controller.

Comment: Why the strange `myObject` wrapper that does nothing? Consider just using `return $firebaseAuth(ref);`

Answer (score 0):

I wanna thank you guys for the possible solutions but it seems that the solution lies in the $timeout variable.

Because the registration function below talks with an API and i am working from a local environment using GulpJS there is a delay in talking between my script and the Firebase API.

```
$scope.register = function (){ 
Authentication.register($scope.user)
    .then(function(user){
        Authentication.login($scope.user);                                                      
    })
    .then(function(user){
        $timeout(function(){
            $location.path('/meetings');
        }, 5);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        $scope.message = error.toString();
    });


} //register
```

Thats why i put a $timeout angular function in there in the first place but i forgot that the number 5 in input in the $timeout function is in milliseconds and it seems because of my setup(using a local environment while talking to the Firebase API online) i found that if i use a 2 second delay in the redirection now ng-show changes automatically without manually refreshing the page.

correct code would be the one below:

```
$scope.register = function (){ 
    Authentication.register($scope.user)
        .then(function(user){
            Authentication.login($scope.user);                                                      
        })
        .then(function(user){
            $timeout(function(){
                $location.path('/meetings');
            }, 2000);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            $scope.message = error.toString();
        });
} //register
```

I suspect that if i use my angular app on the web i could possibly lower the delay or even remove the $timeout function completely.